# vimrc search and replace all excluding previous matches

Tags: regex, vim, replace

So I have two functions in my vimrc which I use a lot:

```
function! FindAndReplaceAllConfirm(from, to) 
  exec '%s/' . a:from . '/' . a:to . '/gc'
endfunction

function! FindAndReplaceAll(from, to) 
  exec '%s/' . a:from . '/' . a:to . '/g'
endfunction
```

The problem is consider if I'm replacing Foo with FooBar. Sometimes I already have FooBar in the file and I don't want FooBar becoming FooFooBar. How does one exclude patches like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add word boundaries `\<` and `\>` to match and replace only exact words as in the following function:

```
function! FindAndReplaceAll(from, to)
  exec '%s/\<' . a:from . '\>/' . a:to . '/g'
endfunction
```

Comment: so this partly solves the problem but optimally I would like it to not force a word boundary.

Comment: You will need to force SOME boundary, either word or with a zero-width assertion in your regex. Vim does not remember past search match locations in any way.